# apt-get update is failing in debian 10 buster

Tags: linux, debian

I am currently running debian 10 buster on a beaglebone black and when i try to use the command "sudo apt-get update" i get the following error:

```
Err:1 http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian buster InRelease 
 Temporary failure resolving 'repos.rcn-ee.com'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporar                                                                  y failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease                                                                    Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/In                                                                  Release  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Tempor                                                                  ary failure resolving 'repos.rcn-ee.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used                                                                   instead.
```

I believe there may be an issue with repositories. Currently in my /ect/apt/sources.list file i have the following:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb [arch=armhf] http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/ buster main
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue,thanks.

Comment: Perhaps try sudo  apt autoremove to remove old packages, restart and try again.

Comment: Hey @John, thanks for the response. I tried that but unfortunately i received the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your DNS server/settings are not resolving the FQDN name `deb.debian.org` and `repos.rcn-ee.com`

Check your DNS settings and try to run `apt update` again.

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`
`nameserver 1.1.1.1`
source: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685611/where-should-i-configure-dns-in-debian-11